# Regex to replace every newline

Tags: c#, regex, replace, newline

I need to replace every newline character in a string with another character (say 'X'). I do **not** wish to collapse multiple newlines with a single newline!

PS: this regex replaces all consecutive newlines with a single newline but its not what I need.

```
Regex regex_newline = new Regex("(\r\n|\r|\n)+");
```

Comment: What's wrong with `str = str.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "X");` ?

Comment: The StackOverflow community expects you to state not only what you need, but also what you have tried to achieve it.

Comment: @Jon, i havent try anything since i dont get along with regexes. So is the Environment.NewLine treating all 3 cases: '\r', '\n' and '\r\n' ?

Comment: osmiumbin I didn't get along with my ex wife so I divorced her and moved on to trying something newer and less complex..so far she works miracles ...lol moral of the story why try something you don't understand when you can use what ever internal functionality is available to you

Comment: Jon dear, you misunderstood me. I didnt come up with a complex problem so you can ask me what i did to achieve it. I asked for a specific small thing that can be answered in 10 characters: the regex pattern to replace every newline. And you ask me what i did to achieve it? Rofl. Stop the downvoting of questions you dont even bother to answer. I was precise in what i want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That will replace one or more newlines with something, not necessarily with a single newline -- that's determined by the regex_newline.Replace(...) call, which you don't show.

So basically, the answer is

```
 Regex regex_newline = new Regex("(\r\n|\r|\n)");   // remove the '+'
 // :
 regex_newline.replace(somestring, "X");
```

Comment: Any reason for using a regular expression instead of the `string.Replace` method?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: from the regex the OP gave, I assume he wants to replace all forms of newlines (Mac, Linux or ASCII) which you can;t do with a simple string.Replace()

Comment: why not? The `string.Replace` method can be chained a couple of times.

Comment: Thanks, removing the plus mark was the answer. I'm guessing the Environment.NewLine does not treat all possible newlines as James Curran said.

Comment: I never said to use `Environment.NewLine`. What I said in my comment is that you could chain multiple calls of `string.Replace` with the exact characters you need to replace covering all cases.

Comment: bottom line i asked for a regex solution and this one is the answer. Not for the Environment.NewLine. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Just use the `String.Replace` method and replace the `Environment.NewLine` in your string. No need for Regex.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx

Comment: The assumes that all newlines in the text are properly formed, while the code he presents assume that they will not be.